# Extract all users from active directory groups from multiple domains using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssis, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I don't have much expertise in Active Directory or Powershell, I need to pull all users and there details belonging to over 1000 security groups.

I've tried few different PS scripts available online but due to the large amount of data the script is taking a really long time to complete (I stopped the script after it kept running for 3 days)

I also tried breaking down the group list and running 100 groups at a time using SSIS but no avail.

I'm using the following 1st script to pull the members of the groups and the 2nd script to pull the rest of the user details

P.S. the groups and users are a mix from multiple sub-domains.

**Script 1:**

```
$groups = Get-Content c:\temp\Groups.txt      
foreach($Group in $Groups) {            
    Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group | select  @{Expression=    {$Group};Label="Group Name"},* | Export-CSV c:\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -    NoTypeInformation
}
```

---

**Script 2:**

```
$objForest =     [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$DomainList = @($objForest.Domains | Select-Object Name)
$Domains = $DomainList | foreach {$_.Name}
$Users = Import-CSV c:\users\public\users.csv
#Act on each domain
foreach($Domain in ($Domains))
{
    Write-Host "Checking $Domain" -fore blue
    Foreach($mail in ($Users.mail))
    {
        Get-ADUser -filter {mail -eq $mail} -Server $domain -properties     mail | select mail,employeeID,title,department,name

        Export-CSV c:\temp\MemberDetails.CSV -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you run your code? If you run it from a remote computer try to run it on your DC.

Comment: @Cavalli - I don't have access to the DC server, I'm running it on a workstation running windows enterprise (not windows server).

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, I have resolved it by running my script locally on my DC. Did you monitored the performances of your workstation when you run the script (cpu usage, memory...)?

Comment: If you are familiar with PowerShell Workflows this may be a good candidate for that. If not you may want to try running this as jobs for pulling the group members so you can query multiple groups at once. Also, are you making sure to remove duplicate user references? Say a user is in 8 of your 1000 groups, are you trying to pull the user info 8 times or just once?

Comment: Also, script 1 overwrites the same file over and over again for each group, so the only results you'll get output for are the last group in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ran this against a group with 4300+ members

it took a couple minutes

```
$groupname = <whatever your group name is>
$servername = <whatever domain your group is with>

$dns = get-adgroup $groupname -server $servername -Properties member | select -ExpandProperty member
    $adobjects = @()
    $objqry = {
        param([string[]]$items)
        function GetAdsiObj {
            param($dn)
            $item = [adsi]$("LDAP://$_")
            $item.setinfo()
            return $item
        }
        return $items | select @{n='adsiobj';e={ GetAdsiObj $_}} | `
            select @{n='samaccountname';e={$_.adsiobj.properties.samaccountname[0]}}, `
                   @{n='name';e={$_.adsiobj.properties.name[0]}}, `
                   @{n='objectclass';e={$_.adsiobj.properties.objectclass[$_.properties.adsiobj.objectclass.count - 1]}}, `
                   @{n='dn';e={$_.adsiobj.path}}, `
                   @{n='useraccountcontrol';e={$_.adsiobj.useraccountcontrol[0]}}
    }
    $jobs = @()

    for($i= 0; $i -lt $dns.Count;$i += 250){
        $data = $dns[$i..$($i + 249)] 
        $jobs += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $objqry -ArgumentList (,$data)
    }

    $runningcount = {
        param($j)
        return $($j | ?{ $_.State -eq "Running" }).Count
    }
    $jobcount = $jobs.Count
    while($(&$runningcount $jobs) -gt 0){
        write-progress -activity "Processing members" -status "Progress:" `
        -percentcomplete (($jobcount- $(&$runningcount $jobs))/$jobcount*100)
    }
    $responses = $jobs | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
    $responses | %{ $adobjects += @($_) }
    $adobjects
```

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know how much of an answer this is, but it's more than a comment can accommodate. So what I would do is make an empty hashtable, query a group's members, and create an entry for each user in the hashtable. Then for each additional group I'd get the members, and I would check against the hashtable to see if I already had the user info, and if I didn't I would query that user and add it to the hashtable. Hm, maybe even have two hashtables, one for the groups, and each group would have the group name as the key, and the list of users as the value, and then you could cross reference the hashtable of users, and you could output all kinds of info that way.

```
$GroupList = Get-Contant c:\temp\Groups.txt
$GroupHash = @{}
$UserHash = @{}
ForEach($Group in $Groups){
    $GroupHash.$Group = Get-ADGroupMember $Group

    ForEach($User in ($GroupHash.$Group|Where{!$UserHash.($_.distinguishedName)})){
        $UserHash.($User.distinguishedName) = Get-ADUser $User.distinguishedName -Server $($User.distinguishedName -replace "^.*?DC=" -replace ",DC=", ".") -Prop Mail
    }
}
```

After that you would have `$GroupHash` that would have a list of each group member for each group, and you would have `$UserHash` that contains the user details of any user that could be in any of the groups. Then how you output that info is up to you...

```
ForEach($Group in $GroupHash.Keys){
    $GroupHash.$Group.distinguishedName | ForEach{%UserHash.$_} | Select mail,employeeID,title,department,name | Export-CSV C:\Temp\$Group.csv -NoType
}
```

That would make a CSV file for each group in the C:\Temp folder, and it would contain the user details for everybody in the group.

Now mind you, none of this is recursive, so you aren't getting members of nested groups if there are any, but your original scripts weren't recursive so I didn't go into that.